# Problemas com While

Tags: php, jquery, while

Estou desenvolvendo uma página que deve puxar do banco de dados o nome do conteúdo e o caminho do arquivo HTML que consta esse conteúdo. Na tabela do banco de dados tem duas colunas: conteudo_titulo e conteudo_html. Esse conteúdo não está no banco de dados, apenas o caminho da pasta onde está o arquivo HTML.

**Erro**: Ao puxar do banco de dados e exibir esses dados em painéis, só dá certo na primeira execução do while. Os demais painéis não mostram o conteúdo, apenas o título.

Por gentileza, alguém poderia me ajudar?!

```
<?php
    //Conexão com o banco
    include '../actions/conexao_db.php';

    //Consulta
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM disciplinas;");

    //Exibindo conteúdos em painéis
    while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
        $nomeConteudo = $exibe["nomeConteudo"];
        $arquivoConteudo = $exibe["includeConteudo"];

            echo '<br><div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">' . $nomeConteudo . '</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                    $("#divConteudo").load("' . $arquivoConteudo . '");
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                </div>';

    }                   
?>
```

Comment: voce tem que usar a cada iteracao do seu `while` uma `$("#divConteudo")` diferente, senao a cada passagem que voce faz pelo while voce estara alterando a mesma div

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda André Paulo, era isso mesmo, já corrigi e rodou certinho agora. Desculpe a demora. Vlw!!